# Struts2 + Hibernate query result is empty

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, struts2

Im trying to collect the result from the query but the list is empty when I check the log in my console. The login action works perfectly but obtain the query result is somewhat not happening. I also used size() to check but it also brings a zero size. What am I missing here

See my dao class:

**UserDAO.java**

```
 public User userLogin(String email, String password) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
   User userinfo = new User();

    try {

        String hql = "select * from user where email =:email and password =:password";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
        query.addEntity(User.class);
        query.setParameter("email", email);
        query.setParameter("password", password);

        List rows = query.list();

        System.out.println("Total Number Of Records : " + rows.size());

        Iterator myItr = rows.iterator();

        while (myItr.hasNext()) {
            Object  ui = (Object) myItr.next();
            userinfo = (User) ui;
            System.out.println("Username : " + userinfo.getUsername());

        }
        if (userinfo != null) {
            System.out.println("User Retrieved from DB::" + userinfo);
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // close your session
        session.close();
    }

    return userinfo;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that your query is actually returning nothing.  userinfo will never be NULL because it is instantiated " User userinfo = new User();".   Debug your values for email and password and then try to run the same query on your db in a query manager and that should help find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Query` hibernate and use  `uniqueResult()`:

```
String hql = "from user where email =:email and password =:password";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("email", email);
query.setParameter("password", password);
User userinfo = (User) query.uniqueResult();
```